# What are the pros and cons of automated Unit Tests vs automated Integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

Recently we have been adding automated tests to our existing java applications.

**What we have**

The majority of these tests are integration tests, which may cover a stack of calls like:-

1. HTTP post into a servlet
2. The servlet validates the request and calls the business layer
3. The business layer does a bunch of stuff via hibernate etc and updates some database tables
4. The servlet generates some XML, runs this through XSLT to produce response HTML.

We then verify that the servlet responded with the correct XML and that the correct rows exist in the database (our development Oracle instance).  These rows are then deleted.

We also have a few smaller unit tests which check single method calls.

These tests are all run as part of our nightly (or adhoc) builds.

**The Question**

This seems good because we are checking the boundaries of our system: servlet request/response on one end and database on the other.  If these work, then we are free to refactor or mess with anything inbetween and have some confidence that the servlet under test continues to work.

What problems are we likely to run into with this approach?

I can't see how adding a bunch more unit tests on individual classes would help.  Wouldn't that make it harder to refactor as it's much more likely we will need to throw away and re-write tests?

Comment: Pragmatically, your approach is probably fine as long as the business logic stays simple. Problems begin once it gets too complicated to be properly tested by the integration test. Introduce more unit tests as soon as you start getting nervous when modifying the business logic. See this [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25976990/2810305).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are asking pros and cons of two different things (what are the pros and cons of riding a horse vs riding a motorcycle?)

Of course both are "automated tests" (~riding) but that doesn't mean that they are alternative (you don't ride a horse for hundreds of miles, and you don't ride a motorcycle in closed-to-vehicle muddy places)

---

**Unit Tests** test the smallest unit of the code, usually a method. Each unit test is closely tied to the method it is testing, and if it's well written it's tied (almost) only with that.

They are great to guide the *design* of new code and the *refactoring* of existing code. They are great to spot problems long before the system is ready for integration tests. Note that I wrote *guide* and all the Test Driven Development is about this word.

It does not make any sense to have manual Unit Tests.

What about refactoring, which seems to be your main concern? If you are refactoring just the implementation (content) of a method, but not its existence or "external behavior", the Unit Test is still valid and incredibly useful (you cannot imagine how much useful until you try).

If you are refactoring more aggressively, changing methods existence or behavior, then yes, you need to write a new Unit Test for each new method, and possibly throw away the old one. But writing the Unit Test, especially if you write it before the code itself, will help to clarify the design (i.e. **what** the method should do, and **what** it shouldn't) without being confused by the implementation details (i.e. **how** the method should do the thing that it needs to do).

---

**Automated Integration Tests** test the biggest unit of the code, usually the entire application.

They are great to test *use cases* which you don't want to test by hand. But you can also have manual Integration Tests, and they are as effective (only less convenient).

---

Starting a new project today, it does not make any sense not to have Unit Tests, but I'd say that for an existing project like yours it does not make too much sense to write them for everything you already have and it's working.

In your case, I'd rather use a "middle ground" approach writing:

1. smaller Integration Tests which only test the sections you are going to refactor. If you are refactoring the whole thing, then you can use your current Integration Tests, but if you are refactoring only -say- the XML generation, it does not make any sense to require the presence of the database, so I'd write a simple and small XML Integration Test.
2. a bunch of Unit Tests for the new code you are going to write. As I already wrote above, Unit Tests will be ready as soon as you "mess with anything in between", making sure that your "mess" is going somewhere.

In fact your Integration Test will only make sure that your "mess" is not working (because at the beginning it will not work, right?) but it will not give you any clue on

- why it is not working
- if your debugging of the "mess" is really fixing something
- if your debugging of the "mess" is breaking something else

Integration Tests will only give the confirmation at the end if the whole change was successful (and the answer will be "no" for a long time). The Integration Tests will not give you any help during the refactoring itself, which will make it harder and possibly frustrating. You need Unit Tests for that.

Comment: If I'm riding a horse, I can't be riding a motorcycle at the same time.

Comment: I have to disagree with some of this answer.  With a 'legacy' project you should be moving toward full coverage.  You should be working on full integration tests, and there's nothing stopping you if you're testing through the app's user interface.  Yes, you should put things under unit test as you add them, but you should also be putting things under test as you change them.  If you only look toward new code under test, too often you'll find you can't without changing the old and you'll stop.  Any change should be unit tested if possible.

Answer (score 35):

Unit tests localize failures more tightly.  Integration-level tests more closely correspond to user requirements and so are  better predictor of delivery success.  Neither of them is much good unless built and maintained, but both of them are very valuable if properly used.

---

(more...)

The thing with units tests is that no integration level test can exercise all the code as much as a good set of unit tests can.  Yes, that can mean that you have to refactor the tests somewhat, but in general your tests shouldn't depend on the internals so much.  So, lets say for example that you have a single function to get a power of two.  You describe it (as a formal methods guy, I'd claim you specify it)

```
long pow2(int p); // returns 2^p for 0 <= p <= 30
```

Your test and your spec look essentially the same (this is sort of pseudo-xUnit for illustration):

```
assertEqual(1073741824,pow2(30);
assertEqual(1, pow2(0));
assertException(domainError, pow2(-1));
assertException(domainError, pow2(31));
```

Now your implementation can be a for loop with a multiple, and you can come along later and change that to a shift.

If you change the implementation so that, say, it's returning 16 bits (remember that `sizeof(long)` is only guaranteed to be no less  than `sizeof(short)`) then this tests will fail quickly.  An integration-level test should probably fail, but not certainly, and it's just as likely as not to fail somewhere far downstream of the computation of `pow2(28)`.

The point is that they really test for diferent situations.  If you could build sufficiently details and extensive integration tests, you might be able to get the same level of coverage and degree of fine-grained testing, but it's probably hard to do at best, and the exponential state-space explosion will defeat you.  By partitioning the state space using unit tests, the number of tests you need grows much less than exponentially.

Answer (score 20):

I agree with Charlie about Integration-level tests corresponding more to user actions and the correctness of the system as a whole. I do think there is alot more value to Unit Tests than just localizing failures more tightly though. Unit tests provide two main values over integration tests:

1) Writing unit tests is as much an act of design as testing. If you practice Test Driven Development/Behavior Driven Development the act of writing the unit tests helps you design exactly what you code should do. It helps you write higher quality code (since being loosely coupled helps with testing) and it helps you write just enough code to make your tests pass (since your tests are in effect your specification).

2) The second value of unit tests is that if they are properly written they are very very fast. If I make a change to a class in your project can I run all the corresponding tests to see if I broke anything? How do I know which tests to run? And how long will they take? I can guarantee it will be longer than well written unit tests. You should be able to run all of you unit tests in a couple of minutes at the most.

Comment: I do too, but the question was what distinguishes them.

Comment: Right, and I felt that much more distinguished them then just localizing failures.

Comment: Note that we are modifying an existing application.  We're generally adding features and making bug fixes to large portions of existing code.  Our integration tests take around 9 minutes to run at the moment.  They are run nightly.

Comment: Running nightly is great, but good unit tests can run in less than a minute. You can run them throughout the day as you write code, before you check-in, after you check-out, etc. Unit tests are also great when working on bugs, you can write a test to prove that the bug exists, then fix it, prove that it was fixed by a working test, and make sure it won't break again.

Answer (score 16):

Just a few examples from personal experience:

**Unit Tests:**

- (+) Keeps testing close to the relevant code
- (+) Relatively easy to test all code paths
- (+) Easy to see if someone inadvertently changes the behavior of a method
- (-) Much harder to write for UI components than for non-GUI

**Integration Tests:**

- (+) It's nice to have nuts and bolts in a project, but integration testing makes sure they fit each other
- (-) Harder to localize source of errors
- (-) Harder to tests all (or even all critical) code paths

*Ideally both are necessary.*

**Examples:**

- Unit test: Make sure that input index >= 0 and < length of array. What happens when outside bounds? Should method throw exception or return null?
- Integration test: What does the user see when a negative inventory value is input?

The second affects both the UI and the back end. Both sides could work perfectly, and you could still get the wrong answer, because the error condition between the two isn't well-defined.

The best part about Unit testing we've found is that it makes devs go from code->test->think to think->test->code. If a dev has to write the test first, [s]he tends to think more about what could go wrong up front.

To answer your last question, since unit tests live so close to the code and force the dev to think more up front, in practice we've found that we don't tend to refactor the code as much, so less code gets moved around - so tossing and writing new tests constantly doesn't appear to be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

The question has a philisophical part for sure, but also points to pragmatic considerations.

Test driven design used as the means to become a better developer has its merits, but it is not required for that.  Many a good programmer exists who never wrote a unit test. The best reason for unit tests is the power they give you when refactoring, especially when many people are changing the source at the same time.  Spotting bugs on checkin is also a huge time-saver for a project (consider moving to a CI model and build on checkin instead of nightly).  So if you write a unit test, either before or after you written the code it tests, you are sure at that moment about the new code you've written.  It is what can happen to that code later that the unit test ensures against - and that can be significant.  Unit tests can stop bugs before tehy get to QA, thereby speeding up your projects.

Integration tests stress the interfaces between elements in your stack, if done correctly.  In my experience, integration is the most unpredictable part of a project.  Getting individual pieces to work tends not to be that hard, but putting everything together can be very difficult because of the types of bugs that can emerge at this step.  In many cases, projects are late because of what happens in integration.  Some of the errors encountered in this step are found in interfaces that have been broken by some change made on one side that was not communicated to the other side.  Another source of integration errors are in configurations discovered in dev but forgotten by the time the app goes to QA.  Integration tests can help reduce both types dramatically.

The importance of each test type can be debated, but what will be of most importance to you is the application of either type to your particular situation.  Is the app in question being developed by a small group of people or many different groups?  Do you have one repository for everything, or many repos each for a particular component of the app? If you have the latter, then you will have challenges with inter compatability of different versions of different components.

Each test type is designed to expose the problems of different levels of integration in the development phase to save time.  Unit tests drive the integration of the output many developers operating on one repository.  Integration tests (poorly named) drive the integration of components in the stack - components often written by separate teams.  The class of problems exposed by integration tests are typically more time-consuming to fix.

So pragmatically, it really boils down to where you most need speed in your own org/process.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that distinguishes Unit tests and Integration tests is the number of parts required for the test to run.

Unit tests (theoretically) require very (or no) other parts to run.
Integration tests (theoretically) require lots (or all) other parts to run.

Integration tests test behaviour AND the infrastructure. Unit tests generally only test behaviour.

So, unit tests are good for testing some stuff, integration tests for other stuff.

So, why unit test?

For instance, it is very hard to test boundary conditions when integration testing. Example: a back end function expects a positive integer or 0, the front end does not allow entry of a negative integer, how do you ensure that the back end function behaves correctly when you pass a negative integer to it? Maybe the correct behaviour is to throw an exception. This is very hard to do with an integration test.

So, for this, you need a unit test (of the function).

Also, unit tests help eliminate problems found during integration tests. In your example above, there are a lot of points of failure for a single HTTP call:

the call from the HTTP client
the servlet validation
the call from the servlet to the business layer
the business layer validation
the database read (hibernate)
the data transformation by the business layer
the database write (hibernate)
the data transformation -> XML
the XSLT transformation -> HTML
the transmission of the HTML -> client

For your integration tests to work, you need ALL of these processes to work correctly. For a Unit test of the servlet validation, you need only one. The servlet validation (which can be independent of everything else). A problem in one layer becomes easier to track down.

You need both Unit tests AND integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests execute methods in a class to verify proper input/output without testing the class in the larger context of your application. You might use mocks to simulate dependent classes -- you're doing black box testing of the class as a stand alone entity. Unit tests should be runnable from a developer workstation without any external service or software requirements.

Integration tests will include other components of your application and third party software (your Oracle dev database, for example, or Selenium tests for a webapp). These tests might still be very fast and run as part of a continuous build, but because they inject additional dependencies they also risk injecting new bugs that cause problems *for* your code but are not caused *by* your code. Preferably, integration tests are also where you inject real/recorded data and assert that the application stack as a whole is behaving as expected given those inputs.

The question comes down to what kind of bugs you're looking to find and how quickly you hope to find them. Unit tests help to reduce the number of "simple" mistakes while integration tests help you ferret out architectural and integration issues, hopefully simulating the effects of Murphy's Law on your application as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Joel Spolsky has written very interesting article about unit-testing (it was dialog between Joel and some other guy).

The main idea was that unit tests is very good thing but only if you use them in "limited" quantity. Joel doesn't recommend to achive state when 100% of your code is under testcases.

The problem with unit tests is that when you want to change architecture of your application you'll have to change all corresponding unit tests. And it'll take very much time (maybe even more time than the refactoring itself). And after all that work only few tests will fail.

So, write tests only for code that really can make some troubles.

How I use unit tests: I don't like TDD so I first write code then I test it (using console or browser) just to be sure that this code do nessecary work. And only after that I add "tricky" tests - 50% of them fail after first testing.

It works and it doesn't take much time.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you ... sounds like good advice

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [this question and the related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176267/why-should-i-both-unit-test-and-web-test-instead-of-just-web-test/558324#558324) too. There you can find my addition to the answers that were already given here.

Answer (score 2):

We have 4 different types of tests in our project:

1. Unit tests with mocking where necessary
2. DB tests that act similar to unit tests but touch db & clean up afterwards
3. Our logic is exposed through REST, so we have tests that do HTTP
4. Webapp tests using WatiN that actually use IE instance and go over major functionality

I like unit tests. They run really fast (100-1000x faster than #4 tests). They are type safe, so refactoring is quite easy (with good IDE).

Main problem is how much work is required to do them properly. You have to mock everything: Db access, network access, other components. You have to decorate unmockable classes, getting a zillion mostly useless classes. You have to use DI so that your components are not tightly coupled and therefore not testable (note that using DI is not actually a downside :)

I like tests #2. They do use the database and will report database errors, constraint violations and invalid columns. I think we get valuable testing using this.

#3 and especially #4 are more problematic. They require some subset of production environment on build server. You have to build, deploy and have the app running. You have to have a clean DB every time. But in the end, it pays off. Watin tests require constant work, but you also get constant testing. We run tests on every commit and it is very easy to see when we break something.

So, back to your question. Unit tests are fast (which is very important, build time should be less than, say,  10 minutes) and the are easy to refactor. Much easier than rewriting whole watin thing if your design changes. If you use a nice editor with good *find usages* command (e.g. IDEA or VS.NET + Resharper), you can always find where your code is being tested.

With REST/HTTP tests, you get a good a good validation that your system actually works. But tests are slow to run, so it is hard to have a complete validation at this level. I assume your methods accept multiple parametres or possibly XML input. To check each node in XML or each parameter, it would take tens or hundreds of calls. You can do that with unit tests, but you cannot do that with REST calls, when each can take a big fraction of a second.

Our unit tests check special boundary conditions far more often than #3 tests. They (#3) check that main functionality is working and that's it. This seems to work pretty well for us.

Answer (score 2):

As many have mentioned, integration tests will tell you whether your system works, and unit tests will tell you where it doesn't.  Strictly from a testing perspective, these two kinds of tests complement each other.

> I can't see how adding a bunch more
>   unit tests on individual classes would
>   help. Wouldn't that make it harder to
>   refactor as it's much more likely we
>   will need to throw away and re-write
>   tests?

No.  It will make refactoring easier and better, and make it clearer to see what refactorings are appropriate and relevant.  This is why we say that TDD is about design, not about testing.  It's quite common for me to write a test for one method and in figuring out how to express what that method's result should be to come up with a very simple implementation in terms of some other method of the class under test.  That implementation frequently finds its way into the class under test.  Simpler, more solid implementations, cleaner boundaries, smaller methods: TDD - unit tests, specifically - lead you in this direction, and integration tests do not.  They're both important, both useful, but they serve different purposes.

Yes, you may find yourself modifying and deleting unit tests on occasion to accommodate refactorings; that's fine, but it's not hard.  And having those unit tests - and going through the experience of writing them - gives you better insight into your code, and better design.

Answer (score 1):

Although the setup you described sounds good, unit testing also offers something important.  Unit testing offers fine levels of granularity.  With loose coupling and dependency injection, you can pretty much test every important case.  You can be sure that the units are robust; you can scrutinise individual methods with scores of inputs or interesting things that don't necessarily occur during your integration tests.

E.g. if you want to deterministically see how a class will handle some sort of failure that would require a tricky setup (e.g. network exception when retrieving something from a server) you can easily write your own test double network connection class, inject it and tell it to throw an exception whenever you feel like it. You can then make sure that the class under test gracefully handles the exception and carries on in a valid state.