# What's the difference between Unit Testing and Automated Testing?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to use Unit Testing to help deploying WordPress websites, but I wonder if there's a difference between Unit Testing and Automated Testing?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of automated Unit Tests vs automated Integration tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771011/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-automated-unit-tests-vs-automated-integration-test)

Comment: Unit testing is a method of writing tests, automated testing is a method of using tests. So, you cant really compare them as they are different things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general unit testing is meant for the developers. When a developer writes the code he should ensure it is working in most common scenario. In .NET we use NUnit, MSUnit etc to test the code and the logic.

Automated testing usually happens on top of unit tested on the continuous integrated environments. Automated testing usually done by QA by using some tools like Selenium, Protractor, WinRunner etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I am into testing, but i always have strange idea that unit tests are not useful on earth. But your answer made something to think.